# server-side scripting for web pages with Python: nothing happens

Tags: python, mysql, xml

I'm trying to learn to use Python to create dynamic web content. Problem I'm having right out the door, though, is that when I try to do a mySQL query, absolutely nothing happens. There's no error message... it looks like the script simply stops running when I import the module that enables connection to the database.

This does do exactly what I'd expect when I try to run it from the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/xml"
print

#if I type, for example, print "<b>test</b>" here, it appears in the browser window

#msql contains the credentials for connecting to database
#it is NOT in public_html
import msql

#no print instructions after this point are followed

connex=msql.msqlConn()
db=msql.MySQLdb
cursor=connex.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor)

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM userActions")
#run the query

xmlOutput=""

rows=cursor.fetchall()
#output the results
for row in rows:
    xmlOutput+="<action>"
    xmlOutput+="<actionId>"+str(row["actionId"])+"</actionId>"
    xmlOutput+="<userId>"+str(row["userId"])+"</userId>"
    xmlOutput+="<actText>"+str(row["action"])+"</actText>"
    xmlOutput+="<date>"+str(row["dateStamp"])+"</date>"
    xmlOutput+="</action>"

xmlOutput="<list>"+xmlOutput+"</list>"
print xmlOutput
```

This would be my first stab at this, so it merely stands to reason that this should work. I've found nothing online that would suggest otherwise, though.

Comment: Build XML (or HTML) by string concatenation sounds like a very bad idea to me...

Comment: What library is this? msql? Never heard of it.

Comment: When you run it from the command line, what happens? My guess is that your script is getting an error at some point and this is being sent to standard error, so you're not seeing it in the browser. Temporarily adding `import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout` would cause any error message to go to the browser as well.

Comment: What server-side engine are you using? I've had problems with databases and the way that certain engines import sockets... By the way I highly recommend http://codespeak.net/lxml/ to generate xml and pyodbc for database connections...

Answer (score 1):

Please, take 24h to learn something like Django. Django has an ORM and a XML serializer that will make your life easier ensuring proper (and legal) xml, it really pays up.

Comment: OK, will look into Django and pyodbc, at the minimum. Problem turns out to be that the msql module isn't getting found when run through a browser (although it is when run via command line). msql contains boilerplate sign-in code (in a place where the credentials aren't publicly visible), and in turn uses the MySQLdb library.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable cgi traceback to see what happens:

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
```

(I don't think it causes your problem, and clients understand `\n` as well but it is better to use `sys.write("...\r\n")` instead of `print` to print HTTP headers)

Edited: try to add `Content-length: XXXX\r\n` to the header.